# how to keep secrets.yml, so as to build my raills app by semaphoreci.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, secret-key, semaphore-ci

I created my rails app. Then I didn't know , but I need to add secrets.yml to .gitignore and I put it to my repository. I joined the rails app to semaphoreci.com. When  I committed semaphoreci.com builded ok. Later I removed secrets.yml from my repozitory. I did:

```
git rm --cached config/secrets.yml
git rm -r --cashed .
git add .
git commit -m "anything"
```

Now semaphoreci.com don't works. I got:

```
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

  config.secret_key = 'my_key'
```

I think,it happens becouse repo don't contain secrets.yml. I read that I need to keep secrets.yml outside repo.
**How to keep secrets.yml for semaphorecy?**

I tried to use dotenv gem, but I think that if I will add to .gitignore .env file and will add secretts.yml to my repository with code:

```
development:
secret_key_base: ENV['secret_key_base']
```

but I think semaphorecy will not build, becouse in repo  ENV['secret_key_base'] will find .env file, or not?  I don't understand, how can I store my secret_key_base in repository so as to semaphoreci can find it and launch rails server.

Comment: Do you really want to gitignore the entire `secrets.yml` file? For anything else, you can use environment variables to keep the actual keys out of this file.

Comment: development:                                                                                                secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
FACEBOOK_APP_ID: <%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>
FACEBOOK_SECRET: <%= ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"] %>       like this?

Comment: Yes absolutely. This way, you won't need to gitignore your file at all. You can just pass the required values using the environment.

Comment: For passing  export KEY=value?

Comment: Refer to [this guide](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/exporting-environment-variables.html) to know how to set ENV vars in Semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest adding `secrets.yml` to your project as a custom configuration file. For more details please refer to our docs - https://semaphoreci.com/docs/adding-custom-configuration-files.html

If you need any further assistance, feel free to send us a message on support@semaphoreci.com. Looking forward to helping you out!

Milana,
from SemaphoreCI

Comment: I created configuration file  /home/runner/my_app/config/secrets.yml and copied my code from this file. it don't works